# Slow responses from MongoDb with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure

I have recently been working to set up a Mongo db server to act as an object cache for a website. However after setting everything up I am concerned that the performance is quite slow.

It is a single server, not part of a replica set or sharded. I am running all tests from my local machine to the server which is on a Windows Azure VM.

For example I have a collection of approximate 5,500 documents where each document stores a link to an external site. A typical document looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 5001 , 
    "Active" : true , 
    "CategoryId" : 1 , 
    "Crci" : "V" , 
    "CultureId" :  null,
    "DateUpdated" : { "$date" : 1333370987810} ,
    "Description" : "National Careers Service: Childminder" ,
    "Keywords" :  null ,
    "MaxLevel" :  null ,
    "MinLevel" :  null ,
    "PhoneNumber" :  null ,
    "Priority" : 1 , 
    "Title" : "National Careers Service: Childminder" ,
    "WebUrl" : "https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/advice/planning/jobprofiles/Pages/childminder.aspx"
}
```

I tried the following sample query from my code using the official 10gen driver and it took an average of 2.7-3.0 seconds to complete:

```
var query = (from er in lib.All()
             where er.Id > 7000
             select er);
```

(lib is a thin wrapper class  and All() exposes the IQuerable interface)

the query above returns approximately 3000 records.

I have checked the query being generated by the linq and it seems to be fine:

```
{_id: { $gt: 7000} }
```

running the same query from umongo (a GUI interface) returns the results in less than a second which is more what I expected.

The fields are indexed properly using ensure index (called the once when the collection is populated, after that this is read-only data:

```
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder<ExternalResourceView>().Ascending(er => er.Id), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder<ExternalResourceView>().Ascending(er => er.CategoryId));
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder<ExternalResourceView>().Ascending(er => er.Active));
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder<ExternalResourceView>().Ascending(er => er.Keywords));
```

The index seem to be used for the search:

> db.ExternalResources.find({_id: {$gt: 7000}}).explain()

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 3087,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3087,
        "nscanned" : 3087,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 3087,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3087,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 5,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [
                        [
                                7000,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : <Server Name>
}
```

Even single direct id lookups take nearly 100 milliseconds to return in the code, eg:

```
 from er in lib.All()
 where er.Id == 3100
 select er
```

Is there any setup I am missing that would speed up my searches or were my expectations unrealistic to start with?

**Edit:** I have tried completely rebuilding / repopulating the database but it still feels unacceptably slow

**Edit 2:** I am enclosing the wrapper class in its entirety. I don't think it is at fault, but just in case:

```
public abstract class MongoLibrary<TViewModel> : ILibrary<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class
{
    private readonly MongoCollection _collection;
    private readonly string _dbName;
    private readonly string _collectionName;
    private readonly string _connString;

    protected MongoLibrary(string connString, string dbName, string collectionName)
    {
        _connString = connString;
        connString += "/" + dbName;
        var client = new MongoClient(connString);
        _dbName = dbName;
        _collectionName = collectionName;
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(dbName);
        _collection = db.GetCollection<TViewModel>(collectionName);
    }

    public abstract void ConfigureIndex(MongoCollection collection);

    public IQueryable<TViewModel> All()
    {
        return _collection.AsQueryable<TViewModel>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TViewModel> GetWhere(Func<TViewModel, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _collection.AsQueryable<TViewModel>().Where(predicate);
    }

    protected void PopulateData(IEnumerable<TViewModel> views, int instanceToUpdate)
    {
        var ports = //port numbers hidden for security

        foreach (var port in ports)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(string.Format("{0}:{1}/{2}", _connString, port, _dbName));

            var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(_dbName);
            var coll = db.GetCollection(_collectionName);
            coll.Drop();
            coll.InsertBatch(views);
        }
        ConfigureIndex(_collection);
    }

}
```

**Edit 3:** Server logs profiling a query to the database:

The query was just an artificial query to demonstrate performance. The query was:

```
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var temp = _externalResourceLibrary.All().Where(er => er.Id > 7500).ToList();
        sw.Stop();
```

You can see from the logs it authenticated then retrieved the data in 2 trips. in total there 2677 documents retrieved. Time taken was 3580 ms (averaged over 5 runs)

```
>db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()  
{
    "op" : "getmore",
    "ns" : "cache.ExternalResources",
    "query" : {
        "_id" : {
            "$gt" : 7500
        }
    },
    "cursorid" : NumberLong("949848842778037962"),
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(9486),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(4),
            "w" : NumberLong(5)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 2576,
    "responseLength" : 1511874,
    "millis" : 9,
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-01-28T10:52:16.125Z"),
    "client" : <ipAddress>,
    "allUsers" : [
                    {
                        "user" : <username>,
                        "userSource" : <dbName>;
                    }
    ],
    "user" : <username>@<dbName>;
}
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "cache.ExternalResources",
    "query" : {
            "_id" : {
                    "$gt" : 7500
            }
    },
    "cursorid" : NumberLong("949848842778037962"),
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 102,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(749),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(5),
                    "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
    },
    "nreturned" : 101,
    "responseLength" : 64013,
    "millis" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-01-28T10:52:15.954Z"),
    "client" : <ipAddress>,
    "allUsers" : [
            {
                    "user" : <username>,
                    "userSource" : <dbName>;
            }
    ],
    "user" : <username>@<dbName>;
}
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "cache.$cmd",
    "command" : {
            "authenticate" : 1,
            "user" : <username>,
            "nonce" : <nonce>;,
            "key" : <key>;
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 1,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "lockStats" : {
            "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(381),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(9),
                    "w" : NumberLong(3)
            }
    },
    "responseLength" : 79,
    "millis" : 0,
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-01-28T10:52:15.938Z"),
    "client" : <ipAddress>,
    "allUsers" : [
            {
                    "user" : <username>,
                    "userSource" : <dbName>
            }
    ],
    "user" : <username>@<dbName>;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `.All()`, can you try `AsQueryable<T>()` ...?

Comment: I have tried directly using AsQueryable() but it didn't reduce the timings - Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: All things being equal, the 'lib' wrapper I would still look at, have you investigated this at all? If so, when you ran the umongo query, was it on that VM or from a remote location? Just trying to limit the variables here.

Comment: @Joey - It was from my local machine to try and remove as many variables as possible. I have added the wrapper class above, and as you can see the All() function simply exposes the exsisting IQueryable interface. The wrapper is mostly there so it can be injected with the connection string etc

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?

Comment: @CraigWilson We're using v1.8.3

Comment: Your library and `All()` seem decent enough, so the fault is either with how you run the query, how you time it, or the mapping between the document and your `TViewModel`. I suggest you try it without the mapping first (i.e. get a BsonDocument instead of a strongly typed model) and see if that helps. Also, you might want to post some code around the query, including the timing part. You might be enumerating the resulting cursor multiple times.

Comment: Have you seen the mongod server logs if there are any slow queries logged? If not, can you enhance the log level by setting db.setProfilingLevel(2) from mongoshell and see how the queries are logged in log file as well in profiling collection (system.profile in respective databases)?

Comment: @AnilKumar Thank you, i wasn't aware of this command. I've enabled profiling and will post the timings later today, once I have been able to collect some

Comment: @AnilKumar Logs added

Comment: @Avish I have added a sample query with timing code so you can see what i'm running. I don't deserialization is an issue since we're not seeing any CPU spike. I will try as you say leaving as a BSON doc and see if that helps

Comment: It's clear the time is not spent in MongoDB - the queries are running in single digit milliseconds.  What the network between application and DB?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The network is fairly simple (at least until it gets to Microsoft's datacentre). We are a small company and our network is not very large. It goes from my machine through local server/firewall and then straight to the internet. On Azure it is connecting to the VM via a load balancer.

Comment: @Avish As Asya mentioned, it is pretty clear from the profiling logs that MongoDB itself is not taking much time, hardly few millis, and the latency that you see is somewhere in other environmental factors i.e. network, your application, could be something in driver (or how you are using it). Driver is well used by lot of people in community and would assume things may be fine there. To drill-down a bit, can you run the queries from mongo-shell from the same host you are running application and see if that has same response time?

Comment: After spending the day doing profiling it seems it is network latency that is the main problem. When I pushed a build of the websites to Azure and ran it (so the connection would have been entirely inside Microsoft data centre) we saw an immediate speed up by a factor of 10! Thank you everyone for you help on the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues were caused by network latency